# Difficulty setting up a cross-system docker network in NixOS

Tags: l2tp, systemd-networkd, nixos

I've got a collection of docker services that run across multiple servers in a local physical stack.  For reasons, I'm trying to keep the exposed ports as minimal and secured as possible (using authentication, wireguard, and encrypted connections wherever possible).  Because of limited number of systems, and the fact that not all these systems are local (there are some virtual tunnels to other locations), neither Swarm nor Kubernetes is an acceptable alternative.  As such, my current implementation is to use a set of docker-compose configs with a set of wireguard tunnels backing them.

This worked fine till one of my servers hard crashed, and I decided it was time to replace the underlying os with NixOS.  Beyond dealing with Wireguard, Nix has been a blast to use.  Unfortunately, for whatever reason, my use of iptables backed wireguard configs is flaky at best, and I am unable to find any logs suggesting why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't between reboots.

I did, however, find something that seems to be *far* more stable, and far easier to expand: l2tp over Wireguard.  My current planned layout seems to be to generate a set of l2tp tunnels, and make each session on those tunnels a shared docker network.  There's currently only 4 shared networks, which makes the config pretty small, and while there are about 5 total servers in this virtual cluster, they live across 2 separate physical locations, with each location having a bastion node. So the number of actual l2tp tunnels is kept relatively low.  The final step has been to use bridge netdevs to unify the multiple tunnels for each docker network, and lay a ipvlan backed docker network on that bridge.

(all of the above is to cover the x-vs-y possibility.  I'm doing this mostly as a learning exercise, but if there is a much better and easier way to link docker/podman networks between systems, I'm all ears.)

All of the above works as expected when setup manually (mostly via `ip link` commands and the like), and given this is happening across multiple headless servers, I've already setup all the networking configs with networkd.  Unfortunately, while setting up the l2tp netdev configs, I seem to be missing a critical config line somewhere, and cannot get the actual l2tp network devices to ever show up.  I also cannot seem to find any logs anywhere in journalctl about the devices even being attempted to be setup.

I'm including the critical part of my `configuration.nix` ~~as a pastebin~~ (adding it in full here, as requested), but some potentially sensitive info has been scrubbed.

```
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:

{
  networking.useNetworkd = true;

  systemd.network = {
    enable = true;
    networks = {
      "10-lan1" = {
        matchConfig.Name="eno0";
        networkConfig.DHCP = "ipv4";
      };
      "10-wgDocker" = {
        matchConfig.Name = "wg-docker";
        networkConfig = {
          Address = "10.122.1.2/32";
        };
      };
      "10-server2-traefik" = {
        matchConfig.Name="server2-traefik";
        networkConfig = {
          DHCP = "no";
          LinkLocalAddressing = "no";
          Bridge = "br-traefik";
        };
      };
    };
    netdevs = {
      "server2" = {
        enable = true;
        netdevConfig = {
          Name = "l2tpServer2";
          Kind = "l2tp";
        };
        l2tpConfig = {
          EncapsulationType = "ip";
          Local = "10.122.1.2";
          PeerTunnelId = 1;
          Remote = "10.122.1.3";
          TunnelId = 2;
        };
        l2tpSessions = [
          {
            l2tpSessionConfig = {
              Name = "server2-traefik";
              SessionId = 1; 
              PeerSessionId = 2;
            };
          }
          {
            l2tpSessionConfig = {
              Name = "server2-redis";
              SessionId = 3; 
              PeerSessionId = 4;
            };
          }
          {
            l2tpSessionConfig = {
              Name = "server2-postgres";
              SessionId = 5; 
              PeerSessionId = 6;
            };
          }
        ];
      };
      "wg-docker" = {
        enable = true;
        netdevConfig = {
          Name = "wg-docker";
          Kind = "wireguard";
        };
        wireguardConfig = {
          ListenPort = 51821;
          PrivateKeyFile = "/etc/wireguard/docker-wg/private.key";
        };
        wireguardPeers = [
          {
            wireguardPeerConfig = {
              AllowedIPs = [
                "10.122.1.2/32"
              ];
              Endpoint = "server1.example.com:51821";
              PublicKey = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=";
            };
          }
          {
            wireguardPeerConfig = {
              AllowedIPs = [
                "10.122.1.3/32"
              ];
              Endpoint = "server2.example.com:51821";
              PublicKey = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=";
            };
          }
          {
            wireguardPeerConfig = {
              AllowedIPs = [
                "10.122.1.5/32"
              ];
              Endpoint = "server3.example.com:51821";
              PublicKey = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=";
            };
          }
        ];
      };

    };
  };
}
```

As far as I can tell, the key piece missing is adding an `L2TP` line to the `systemd.network.networks."10-wgDocker".networkConfig` block, but while that exists in a standard networkd `[Network]` segment, NixOS says that doesn't exist.  Has anyone else gotten a raw l2tp config setup using NixOS configs on networkd?  Am I missing something here?  a solid hour of searching has come up with just the `nixos.org` search system, which tells me to check `systemd.network(5)` which has no info on actually implementing the l2tp fully, just the netdev config.

Comment: welcome, please always post native text information directly into the question. due links can get invalid for various reasons. it is also required to put logs, config always native inhere. you can double check with [ask] ;)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, though at this point I guess it probably won't matter, since it's been downvoted at least twice with no mentioned reason.  I cant tell if that means I should stop experimenting, or if people don't like NixOS.  Either way given this keeps happening, i'm probably gonna stop asking questions here, since I'm rarely told why people think my questions are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple once I figured out why systemd wasn't logging any errors, though I did go down the rabbit hole of figuring out why it kept showing the error `L2TP tunnel with invalid address family configured`.  The error came from translating existing wireguard `.conf` files into networkd configs.  While wireguard uses the `Address` field to set the local address without a subnet (`10.122.1.2/32`), networkd expects the address to include the subnet (`10.122.1.2/24`).  This lead to the second issue that l2tp just silently fails if the remote address is unreachable.  Setting the `Address` field of the wireguard `networkConfig` correctly allowed the l2tp tunnel to come up cleanly.

The correct config is below:

```
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:

{
  networking.useNetworkd = true;

  systemd.network = {
    enable = true;
    networks = {
      "10-lan1" = {
        matchConfig.Name="eno0";
        networkConfig.DHCP = "ipv4";
      };
      "10-wgDocker" = {
        matchConfig.Name = "wg-docker";
        networkConfig = {
          Address = "10.122.1.2/24";
        };
      };
      "10-server2-traefik" = {
        matchConfig.Name="server2-traefik";
        networkConfig = {
          DHCP = "no";
          LinkLocalAddressing = "no";
          Bridge = "br-traefik";
        };
      };
    };
    netdevs = {
      "server2" = {
        enable = true;
        netdevConfig = {
          Name = "l2tpServer2";
          Kind = "l2tp";
        };
        l2tpConfig = {
          EncapsulationType = "ip";
          Local = "10.122.1.2";
          PeerTunnelId = 1;
          Remote = "10.122.1.3";
          TunnelId = 2;
        };
        l2tpSessions = [
          {
            l2tpSessionConfig = {
              Name = "server2-traefik";
              SessionId = 1; 
              PeerSessionId = 2;
            };
          }
          {
            l2tpSessionConfig = {
              Name = "server2-redis";
              SessionId = 3; 
              PeerSessionId = 4;
            };
          }
          {
            l2tpSessionConfig = {
              Name = "server2-postgres";
              SessionId = 5; 
              PeerSessionId = 6;
            };
          }
        ];
      };
      "wg-docker" = {
        enable = true;
        netdevConfig = {
          Name = "wg-docker";
          Kind = "wireguard";
        };
        wireguardConfig = {
          ListenPort = 51821;
          PrivateKeyFile = "/etc/wireguard/docker-wg/private.key";
        };
        wireguardPeers = [
          {
            wireguardPeerConfig = {
              AllowedIPs = [
                "10.122.1.2/32"
              ];
              Endpoint = "server1.example.com:51821";
              PublicKey = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=";
            };
          }
          {
            wireguardPeerConfig = {
              AllowedIPs = [
                "10.122.1.3/32"
              ];
              Endpoint = "server2.example.com:51821";
              PublicKey = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=";
            };
          }
          {
            wireguardPeerConfig = {
              AllowedIPs = [
                "10.122.1.5/32"
              ];
              Endpoint = "server3.example.com:51821";
              PublicKey = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=";
            };
          }
        ];
      };

    };
  };
}
```